# change url pattern for single page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have (https://www.example.com/details?id=35&task one) url where id and task one text is dynamic  but i want (https://www.example.com/data/task_one)

how can i fix it ??
any body please help. i have no idea how to modify it only for details page. i tried so hard in .htaccess file but nothing resolve

thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

```
    //(url = https://www.example.com/details?id=35&task=task_one)

    $dest = $_GET['task'];
    if($dest=="task_one"){
        header("location:https://www.example.com/data/task_one");
    }
```